# Even if I am storing the value of 1 array into another and print them as a whole but still the array prints the last value

Tags: java, arrays, static

In this code I am having some problem that is I am trying to place the val array values in value array but still the array even though declared static is not storing.

I am not able to figure out the problem. Please help me out.

```
public static int[] val = new int[100]    ;            
    public static int[] value = new int[100];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("An incremented value");
        for(int i=2;i<=2;i++) {
            String p="";
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++) {
                for(int m=0;m<j;m++) {
                    p=p+"&";
                        }
                for(int m=0;m<i-j;m++) {
                    p=p+"|";
                        }
                 printAllPermutations(p);
                p="";

                for(int xy=0;xy<8;xy++){
                value[xy]=val[xy];
            System.out.println("["+xy+"]"+"="+val[xy]+"   ");      
                }
            }
        }
        for(int y=0;y<32;y++)
            System.out.println("["+y+"]"+"="+value[y]+"   ");     

    }
```

the output is::

> ```
> An incremented value
>
> || opr:2    0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1[0]=0   
> [1]=1   
> [2]=1   
> [3]=1   
> [4]=1   
> [5]=1   
> [6]=1   
> [7]=1   
>
> &| opr:2    0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
> |& opr:2    0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1[0]=0   
> [1]=0   
> [2]=0   
> [3]=1   
> [4]=1   
> [5]=1   
> [6]=1   
> [7]=1   
>
> && opr:2    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1[0]=0   
> [1]=0   
> [2]=0   
> [3]=0   
> [4]=0   
> [5]=0   
> [6]=0   
> [7]=1   
> [0]=0   //here in the value array its storing only the last array value.
> [1]=0   
> [2]=0   
> [3]=0   
> [4]=0   
> [5]=0   
> [6]=0   
> [7]=1   
> [8]=0   
> [9]=0   
> [10]=0   
> [11]=0   
> [12]=0   
> [13]=0   
> [14]=0   
> [15]=0   
> [16]=0   
> [17]=0   
> [18]=0   
> [19]=0   
> [20]=0   
> [21]=0   
> [22]=0   
> [23]=0   
> [24]=0   
> [25]=0   
> [26]=0   
> [27]=0   
> [28]=0   
> [29]=0   
> [30]=0   
> [31]=0
> ```

I want the 32 array to show the all 32 values. Please help me out. I dont know where I am going wrong.

Comment: for(int i=2;i<=2;i++) { ?!!!! does this for loop even run?

Comment: It'll execute once

Comment: yes I only want the code to run once and show correct values. I would increment it on getting correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
for(int xy=0;xy<8;xy++){
    value[xy]=val[xy];
    System.out.println("["+xy+"]"+"="+val[xy]+"   ");      
}
```

When you create the value array it's an array of ints.  Because it's an array of ints, all the values are initialised to 0

Now when we get to the loop above, it steps through the first 8 items in array 'value', and assigns them the integer in the corresponding array 'val'.

The reason that you never see anything in the array 'value' beyond value[7] is because you never assign anything to it, you're only copying across the first 8 values.

Comment: ok if thats the problem. Then why I am unable to  make the array static and on storing the 1st 8 values, can it just stay in the same place and store in the next 8 elements.

Comment: You might need to do something like: value[xy + (i*8)]=val[xy + (i*8)] if that makes sense